# Write elevate.xml file from MVC application

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, solr

I use Apache Solr with Dot Net MVC application. Now I want to right query tag in elevate.xml file of Solr from my application.

Structure of elevate.xml file is like:

```
<elevate>
  <query text="foo bar">
    <doc id="1" />
    <doc id="2" />
    <doc id="3" />
  </query>

  <query text="ipod">
    <doc id="MA147LL/A" />  <!-- put the actual ipod at the top -->
    <doc id="IW-02" exclude="true" /> <!-- exclude this cable -->
  </query>
</elevate>
```

same way I want to add other query tag. How can I do it? Is there any API available to write it?

Comment: Do u want add  a new tag in this same xml file ? using c#

Comment: Yes, as there are already two query tag. I want to add others query tag.

Comment: How this is new xml file are you generate this xml in code

Comment: I do not generate xml file. It is already there. I just need to write elements.

Comment: I have given answer below checkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This one

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(strFilename);
XmlElement elmRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlElement elmNew = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
XmlAttribute attribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("text"); //attribute of  query tag
attribute.Value = "foo bar";
elmNew.Attributes.Append(attribute);
elmRoot.AppendChild(elmNew);
xmlDoc.Save(strFilename);
```

strFilename --> Your File name including the path and extension (.xml)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try this

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, it works. Moreover, I have added some few lines to add attributes and their values.

Comment: @Ankita, Ok i have approved it.